# IO Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: (File name too long)

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception

I get a IO Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException:(Filename too long) when I use a BufferedReader to read a file from a url(response is the url response).

```
String payload = response.readAsString();
try(FileReader reader = new FileReader(payload);                    
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
```

The problem seems to be that the contents of the file is read as the file name and it's longer than what's allowed.

To get around this I've used PrintWriter to write the contents to a file and am reading that file but would like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: You probably need to convert from URI to a file path

Comment: A FileReader is used to read... from a file. You want to read from a String. There is a ... StringReader class to do that. More probably, your response has a getInputStream() method. And there is also an ... InputStreamReader class to read from an InputStream. Learn to read the javadoc of the classes and packages you use, instead of trying random things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down a different route in the end.

```
String payload = response.readAsString();               
    try{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(payload);
        JsonNode vaultsNode = root.path("responseData").path("vaults");
        ...
```